# Different approaches to label data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, data-mining, feature-selection

I have a dataset of patient records but they don't have labels.

I would like to label them and would like to know what are the different approaches available that I can consider to label them.

For ex:  I have given two approaches below but is there any other approaches to it?

1) Manual labeling

2) Rule based

3) ..

4) ..

As you all are experienced in data science and AI

Can you please share some approaches that you know and resources that I can refer to learn about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Manual labeling--- this is not as bad as it sounds. Especially when you apply transfer learning, and for most of the datasets you have a lot of pre-trained models. There are [products](https://lionbridge.ai/articles/best-data-labeling-tools-machine-learning-projects/) for that, but also inline python [libraries](https://pypi.org/project/pylabels/)

2) Rule based--- not advisible, since your model will just focus on these if-else rules itself. It would be the the best if these are the rules that are not that visible in the dataset, and the model cant catch it so easily. Which just implies it will than start to learn information in other features that also could be valuable.

3) [Pseudo Labeling](https://www.kaggle.com/cdeotte/pseudo-labeling-qda-0-969)---- will add confident predicted test data to your training data. Therefore you will reinforce the clear labeled data and use them to help and label/predict other ones. Note, its a potential overfitting method.

4) Unsupervised Approach---- try to find good representation of data. The one thats discriminative enough, than apply clustering algos. If the resulting clusters are clear and different, you can look a couple of samples from every cluster and conclude what are the labels for every sample in your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted

Comment: May I also check with you on whether rule based labeling can be called as semi-supervised approach?

Comment: its rather pseuod labeling in my eyes

Answer (score 1):

A decent simple approach is:

- Label *some* data, either manually, or by applying rules to get some unreliable labels with something like https://github.com/snorkel-team/snorkel
- Build a model.
- Assess which outputs are least certain with something like https://github.com/modAL-python/modAL
- Label those manually.
- Repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted.